# How to make the right yii2 validation manually?

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii2

It should be on the page where a list of users , open the modal window for editing . This page should not be updated . Clicking on the link opens a modal window ActiveForm after the data filled by AJAX. How can I transfer that is now id like to pass validation . With help yii.ActiveForms.js or something else?

```
  public function actionEditUser($id) {

if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest && Yii::$app->user->identity->role == 2) {
  $model = new EditUserForm();
  $model->id = (int) $id;
  if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
    Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    return ActiveForm::validate($model);
  }
  if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->updateUser()) {
    return Yii::$app->response->redirect(Url::to(Yii::$app->request->referrer, true));
  } else {
    $user = $this->findModel($id);
    $model->login = $user->login;
    $model->email = $user->email;
    $model->fullName = $user->full_name;
    return $this->renderAjax('editModalUserForm', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
  }
}
return Yii::$app->response->redirect(Url::to('site/sign-in', true));
```

}

```js
  InitEditUser: function (event) {
    var target = $(event.target);
    var id = target.attr('id');
    var url = 'http://' + window.location.hostname + '/users/' + id;
    var urlGet = window.location.href;
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: urlGet,
      data: 'id=' + id,
      success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log('ok');

      },
      error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {


      }
    });




    $('#editUser').modal('show');


    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: url,
      success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log(data);
        $('#editUserInput').val(data.login);
        $('#editUserFullNameInput').val(data.full_name);
        $('#editUserEmailInput').val(data.email);

        $('#editUserForm').on('beforeSubmit', function () {
          console.log("a");
          return false;
        });
        $('#editUserForm').on('afterValidate', function () {
          console.log("b");
        });


      },
      error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {


      }
    });

  },
};
  InitEditUser: function (event) {

var target = $(event.target);
var id = target.attr('id');
var url = 'http://' + window.location.hostname + '/users/' + id;
var urlGet = window.location.href;
```

$.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: urlGet,
      data: 'id=' + id,
      success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log('ok');
         },
      error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      }
    });

```
$('#editUser').modal('show');


$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: url,
  success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    console.log(data);
    $('#editUserInput').val(data.login);
    $('#editUserFullNameInput').val(data.full_name);
    $('#editUserEmailInput').val(data.email);

    $('#editUserForm').on('beforeSubmit', function () {
      console.log("a");
      return false;
    });
    $('#editUserForm').on('afterValidate', function () {
      console.log("b");
    });


  },
  error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

  }
});
```

},
};